# What is the meaning of "pass on news"?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, phrasal-verbs

What is the meaning of "pass on news" in this sentence?

> Social networking helps people pass on news.

Comment: pass on means give something you received from someone to some other person.and that person also give that to other.that chain continues infinitive..so it helps to spread broadly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Pass on* most likely means "to spread, to share".

> [pass on](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/pass-on)
>   [transitive] to give someone something that someone else has given you

So

> Social networking helps people **spread** the news.